# Opening a serial RS232 Port in C with Function CreateFile(..)

Tags: c, windows

```
   HANDLE hPort = CreateFile(
    COM1,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL
    );
```

Will this Function return a value unless zero when no device is connected to the COM port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly the question you're asking actually is, but the `CreateFile` call in your example will only fail for one of the two following reasons:

- There is no `COM1` device. This can be because there's no physical serial port in system, Windows failed to detect it, or Windows assigned it a different COM port number.
- The `COM1` device has already been opened. Windows only allows a serial device to be opened once. Any further attempts to open the port will fail.

When `CreateFile` fails it will return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. The call will not fail because there's is no cable or device attached to the serial port. Windows can only detect whether the serial port itself is present, it can't generally detect whether something is connected to the serial port.